# what is the difference between pseudo convexity and quasi convexity?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I have difficulties in understanding the differences between pseudo convex and quasi convex functions. For example a fractional convex/concave function is pseudo convex or quasi convex?

Comment: Plz attach the definitions.

Answer (score 5):

For simplicity, let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

---

$f$ is said to be [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) if
$$
f(\lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f(y)\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\text{ and }\lambda\in[0,1].
$$
That is, for any points $x,y$, the line joining $(x,f(x))$ to $(y,f(y))$
has to lie above the function $f$.

---

$f$ is said to be [quasiconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) if
$$
f(\lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y)\leq\max\left\{ f(x),f(y)\right\} \text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\text{ and }\lambda\in[0,1].
$$
That is, for any points $x,y$ such that (without loss of generality)
$f(x)\geq f(y)$, the line joining $(x,f(x))$ to $(y,f(x))$ has
to lie above the function $f$. Since the line joining $(x,f(x))$
to $(y,f(x))$ lies above the line joining $(x,f(x))$ to $(y,f(y))$,
any convex function is trivially a quasiconvex function.

---

$f$ is said to be [pseudoconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoconvex_function) if it is once-differentiable and
$$
\nabla f(x)^{\top}(y-x)\geq0\implies f(y)\geq f(x)\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$
Note that if $f$ is convex and once-differentiable, by the first-order
characterization of convexity,
$$
f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^{\top}(y-x)\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$
Therefore, $f$ is pseudoconvex. Note, however, that the converse
is not necessarily true (consider $x\mapsto x+x^{3}$).

---

It's also possible to show that a pseudoconvex function is strictly quasiconvex [1], which is a stronger requirement than being quasiconvex. A concise summary of the above facts is (for once-differentiable functions)

$$
\text{convex}\implies\text{pseudoconvex}\implies\text{strictly quasiconvex}\implies\text{quasiconvex}
$$

---

An expository paper that is a great starting point for learning about these functions is given below.

[1] Mangasarian, Olvi L. ["Pseudo-convex functions."](http://samples.sainsburysebooks.co.uk/9781483273990_sample_809539.pdf#page=40) *Journal of the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, Series A: Control* 3.2 (1965): 281-290.

---

**Addendum:** It seems as though [fractional convex functions are related to quasiconvexity and pseudoconvexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_programming).